# Grails app, with access to DB from Java DAO services - How to access services in Controller?

Tags: java, json, spring, grails, dao

We are creating a Grails app to get the benefit of controller/view features such as gsp layout and view templating, asset-pipeline, LESS CSS compilation, JavaScript and CSS concatenation and minification.  However, because of Hibernate difficulties with complex query structures, we have been forbidden by management to use the Grail domain models and GORM.  Our approach then has been to write Java DAO services to access the Oracle DB, then access the data objects from Grail controllers and deliver as JSON objects to the view.  We are having difficulty finding examples of how to access the data in the controllers.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting? What have you tried? You need to post more details about the code you are using. This question is too broad as it is and it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: We have yet to write the code, thus the need for examples on how to do it.  All we have is a basic Grails app, and need to know how to set it up to use a more traditional data access layer and not use the built in groovy domain classes built on hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define your Java DAOs as `Spring beans` in `conf/spring/resources.groovy[or .xml]`:

```
beans = {
  myComplexDAOOne MyComplexDAOOne 
  daoTwo DaoTwo
}
```

then you should be able to access them per `autowiring` in a controller or any other `Grails artefact`:

```
class MyController {
  def myComplexDAOOne 
  def daoTwo

  def index(){
    def res = myComplexDAOOne.someMethod()
    [ res:res ]
  }
}
```